# How to use Array in JCommander in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, jcommander

I want to use JCommander to parse args.

I wrote some code:

```
import com.beust.jcommander.{JCommander, Parameter}
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Config {
  @Parameter(names = Array("--categories"), required = true)
  var categories = new ArrayBuffer[String]
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val cfg = Config
    JCommander
      .newBuilder()
      .addObject(cfg)
      .build()
      .parse(args.toArray: _*)
    println(cfg.categories)
  }
}
```

Howewer it fails with

```
com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Could not invoke null
    Reason: Can not set static scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer field InterestRulesConfig$.categories to java.lang.String
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

JCommander uses knowledge about types in Java to map values to parameters. But Java doesn't have a type `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`. It has a type [`java.util.List`](https://jcommander.org/#_lists). If you want to use JCommander you have to stick to Java's build-in types.

If you want to use Scala's types use one of Scala's libraries that handle in in more idiomatic manner: [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) or [decline](https://github.com/bkirwi/decline).

Comment: I got it - i have to use `var categories = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]()` in Config, but why when i am trying to apply toArray to cfg.categories i got something like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@21a947fe`

Comment: Full code:
`val a = cfg.categories.toArray`
`println(a.getClass())`

Comment: That's how JVM prints arrays (of `Object`s). `Array`s are _not_ `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```
import java.util

import com.beust.jcommander.{JCommander, Parameter}

import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._


object Config {
  @Parameter(names = Array("--categories"), required = true)
  var categories: java.util.List[Integer] = new util.ArrayList[Integer]()

}

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val cfg = Config
    JCommander
      .newBuilder()
      .addObject(cfg)
      .build()
      .parse(args.toArray: _*)
    println(cfg.categories)
    println(cfg.categories.getClass())
    val a = cfg.categories.asScala
    for (x <- a) {
      println(x.toInt)
      println(x.toInt.getClass())
    }
  }
}
```